# How to repeat async call?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asynchronous

I have a program which does a simple http get in an async call and writes it to the console:

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;

namespace Hello 
{
    class Program
    {
        private static readonly HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
       static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            await ProcessRepositories();
        }
        private static async Task ProcessRepositories()
        {
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            var stringTask = client.GetStringAsync("https://localhost:8080");
            var msg = await stringTask;
            Console.Write(msg);                
        }
    }
}
```

How could I repeat the whole process to make it write it to the console until a button is pressed?

Comment: Think of your basic programming building blocks, which one of those foundational concepts allows you to repeat or _loop_ some section of code?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.cancelkeypress?view=net-6.0

Comment: I wanted to place it in a while loop like this:
```
while (!Console.KeyAvailable) {
   Console.WriteLine("Loop");
 }
```
But it did not work

Comment: @Sanchez82 `it did not work` what did not work? Calling `ProcessRepositories` inside  loop is simple enough.

Comment: it gives an error:
Unhandled exception. System.InvalidOperationException: Cannot see if a key has been pressed when either application does not have a console or when console input has been redirected from a file. Try Console.In.Peek.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class Program
{
    private static readonly HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            var consoleKey = Console.ReadKey().Key;
            if (consoleKey == ConsoleKey.Enter) // if pressed Enter
                await ProcessRepositories();
            else if (consoleKey == ConsoleKey.Escape) // if pressed Esc
                break;
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Finish");
    }

    private static async Task ProcessRepositories()
    {
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear(); // idk why you cleaning headers, but OK
        Console.Write(await client.GetStringAsync("https://localhost:8080"));
    }
}
```

Comment: There's no reason to clear the default headers every time - just don't set them. If each call needs different headers, `GetAsync` should be used instead of `GetStringAsync`

Comment: this one gets the following error: "Unhandled exception. System.InvalidOperationException: Cannot see if a key has been pressed when either application does not have a console or when console input has been redirected from a file. Try Console.In.Peek."

Comment: @Sanchez82 Check Updated code. Pressing `Enter` key in this solution calling srv

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Polly library](https://Link:%20https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly) for such calls. Do not use infinity loop, it is bad practice.

Here is an example about [retry with exponential backoff](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/implement-resilient-applications/implement-http-call-retries-exponential-backoff-polly).

Answer (score 0):

To keep processing data *until* a key is pressed;

```cs
private static readonly HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

public static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    var tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
    var process = ProcessRepositories(tokenSource.Token);

    Console.ReadKey();

    tokenSource.Cancel();
    try
    {
        await process;
    }
    catch (OperationCanceledException) { }
}

private static async Task ProcessRepositories(CancellationToken token = default)
{
    while (!token.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        Console.Write(await client.GetStringAsync("https://localhost:8080", token));
        await Task.Delay(30_000);
    }
}
```